# Behaviour of SAML when HTTP Server used for high availability

Tags: saml, high-availability, httpserver, spring-saml, ibmhttpserver

I have implemented the supporting of SAML SSO to have my application act as the Service Provider using Spring Security SAML Extension. I was able to integrate my SP with different IDPs. So for example I have **HostA,HostB, and HostC**, all these have different instances of my application. I had an SP metadata file specified for each host and set the AssertionConsumerServiceURL with the URL of that host(    EX:https:HostA.com/myapp/saml/sso    ). **I added each metadata file to the IDP and tested all of them and it is working fine.**

**However, my project also supports High Availability by having an IBM HTTP Server configured for load balancing.** So in this case the **HTTP Server will configure the hosts(A,B,C)** to be the hosts used for load balancing, the user will access the my application **using the URL of the HTTP server:    https:httpserver.com/myapp/**

**If I defined one SP metadata file and had the URL of the HTTP Server specified in the AssertionConsumerServiceURL(    https://httpserver.com/saml/sso    )** and changed my implementation to accept assertions targeted to my HTTP Server, **what will be the outcome of this scenario:**

> 1. User accesses the HTTPServer which dispatched the user to HostA(behind the scenes)
> 2. My SP application in HostA sends a request to the IDP for authentication.
> 3. The IDP sends back the response to my httpserver as:    https://httpserver.com/saml/sso    .

**Will the HTTP Server redirect to HostA, to have it like this:     https://HostA.com/saml/sso**

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When deploying same instance of application in a clustered mode behind a load balancer you need to instruct the back-end applications about the public URL on the HTTP server (https://httpserver.com/myapp/) which they are deployed behind. You can do this using the `SAMLContextProviderLB` (see more in the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-load-balancing)). But you seem to have already successfully performed this step.

Once your HTTP Server receives a request, it will forward it to one of your hosts to URL e.g. https://HostA.com/saml/sso and usually will also provide the original URL as an HTTP header. The `SAMLContextProviderLB` will make the SP application think that the real URL was https://httpserver.com/saml/sso which will make it pass all the SAML security checks related to destination URL.

As the back-end applications store state in their HttpSessions make sure to do one of the following:

- enable sticky session on the HTTP server (so that related requests are always directed to the same server
- make sure to replicate HTTP session across your cluster
- disable checking of response ID by including bean `EmptyStorageFactory` in your Spring configuration (this option also makes Single Logout unavailable)

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I will try this solution and get back to you with the results.

Comment: I installed the HTTP Server and made the changes advised above and it worked fine. Thank you.